# How To Merge Data From Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have **two tables**, **L1 and L2** and i want to merge data of these two tables, I want to **fetch sum of sale as per item_id according to dates**,I want to fetch data from **2012-01-20 to 22-01-2012**,L1 table is containing data from 2012-01-20 to 2012-01-21 and L2 tables is containing data of 2012-01-22. please help me out.

Table L1

```
+-----------------+-------+---------
| date            | sale  | item_id |
+-----------------+-------+---------+
|2012-01-20       | 20    |A        | 
|2012-01-20       | 10    |B        |
|2012-01-21       | 20    |A        |
|2012-01-21       | 30    |B        |
|                 |       |         |
+----+-------------+-----------------

Table L2

+-----------------+-------+----------
| date            | sale  | item_id |
+-----------------+-------+---------+
|2012-01-22       | 20    |A        | 
|2012-01-22       | 10    |B        |     
+----+-------------+-----------------

wanted result

+-------+----------
| sale  | item_id |
+-------+---------+
| 60    |A        | 
| 50    |B        |
+------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a `union all` before the aggregation:

```
select item_id, sum(sale) as sale
from ((select date, sale, item_id
       from l1
      ) union all
      (select date, sale, item_id
       from l2
      )
     ) t
group by item_id;
```

You can add a `where` clause for the date range you want.

Comment: Hi @Gordon ,thanks for reply but in L1 table i want sum(sale) by grouping item_id A and B but when i am using group by with select query of L1 table, i am getting an error::Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: @SuryaRawat . . . The query in my answer has an alias on the subquery.  That is what `t` is.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the error refers to the inner tables ... should the query be as follows?:

> select item_id, sum(sale) as sale
>    from ((select date, sale, item_id
>          from l1
>         ) ALIAS1 union all
>         (select date, sale, item_id
>          from l2
>         ) ALIAS2
>        ) t
>   group by item_id;